# User list api with query for org unit also gives sub org unit users

Tags: google-api, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

I'm using the api call like `/admin/directory/v1/users?domain=domain.com&query=orgUnitPath=/Sales` and users in that org unit but say I also have a sub orgunit like `/Sales/California` and more users there. Is there a way to only get the users in `/Sales` and not the sub org units?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you need to filter locally on the specific OrgUnit you want.